# At the end of the day And By the end of the day

Tags: grammaticality, expressions, prepositions

**At the end of the day And By the end of the day**

I am confusing to use this words 
What is the differents between these words, Could your please some scenario of this two words

Thanks

Comment: Do not vandalise your post. This may result in a question ban. see [question bans](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**At the end of the day** is either literally talking about the end of the day (for example, 'We had our dinner at the end of the day'), or a phrase used to say **taking everything into consideration** (for example, 'At the end of the day, we tried our hardest but failed to win').

**By the end of the day** is commonly used with a command such as 'Get this report done by the end of the day'. It could also be used like 'He was worn out by the end of the day'.

Comment: At the end of the day, it's 11:59pm.

Comment: By the end of the day is any time between now and the end of the day (before midnight for a full 24h day, or before 5pm if talking about a stereotypical working day).